# Ruby rookie here : Need help in printing a one sided pyramid using a given Integer

Tags: ruby

input integer 6

output :

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5 6

Tried with loops but failed to get the output.

Comment: "Tried with loops" -> Great! You should [edit] your question and 1) add the code you have, and 2) describe which part isn't working (wrong output, error, etc.), 3) describe the input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
def pyramid(i)
  (1..i).each do |n|
      1.upto(n) do |x|
        print "#{x} " # Mind double quotes
      end
      puts
  end
end

pyramid(6)
```

Read more about [Ruby I/O](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html)

Read more about [loops in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html)